# cifs multiuser mount works at first, but "Permission denied" after a while

Tags: permissions, samba, cifs

I have several Samba shares hosted on a TrueNAS-Scale server, and mount them with the "multiuser" option from an Arch Linux machine. After `cifscreds add` as my user, I can access the share, but after some time I no longer have access, and apparently my session keyring is revoked. Why?

On the Arch machine, I have systemd mount units enabled for each share like this:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/mnt-share.mount
[Unit]
Description=Mount share
After=nss-lookup.target

[Mount]
What=//truenas-scale.localdomain/share
Where=/mnt/share
Type=cifs
Options=multiuser,sec=ntlmssp,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials/smbnobody.creds,iocharset=utf8,rw

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(`/etc/samba/credentials/smbnobody.creds` contains username / password for user `smbnobody`, which I created on the TrueNAS server specifically to have minimal privileges to the shares, i.e. read privileges to the top level directory and nothing else.)

After a fresh boot, I SSH into the Arch machine, run `cifscreds add truenas-scale.localdomain` and type in the password, and I can have read / write access to `/mnt/share` as expected. I then start `tmux`, start a long-running task, and disconnect.

When I SSH back into the Arch machine after a while, often I find myself no longer having read / write access to `/mnt/share`:

```
$ ls /mnt/share
ls: cannot access '/mnt/share': Permission denied

$ ls -l /mnt
ls: cannot access '/mnt/share': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? share
```

Attempting to add / update credentials also fails:

```
$ cifscreds add truenas-scale.localdomain
Error: unable to query session keyring: Key has been revoked

$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
Unable to dump key: Key has been revoked
```

I have to reboot the machine to gain access again.

This issue occurs if my long-running task does not access the share. If, for example, I run `wget` to download a large file to the share inside `tmux`, disconnect, and reconnect before the download completes, then read / write access to the share is still working. However, if I reconnect only after the download has completed, then I see "Permission denied".

Why does this happen, and how should I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issue myself, which in my case I could workaround by creating a new session with `keyctl session` and authenticate into it.

I know, it's an unsatisfactory answer, but hopefully it's best than the others you've got so far (i.e. none) and might give you some clues to build on.